# Create constraints with code - getting error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints"

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I added a UIView in the storyboard (called swipedView) and I didn't set any auto-layout constraints to it. Nothing. Now in the code, I want to add some constraints. To test it out I want to pin it to the sides of the screen (so it's fullscreen).

When I run it, I get a long error message, something like:

```
2016-07-18 22:59:07.990 FindTheWay[87145:18423835] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff02d11a6e0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff02b479a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff02b450100 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7ff02b416a50 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(20)-[UIView:0x7ff02b479a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff02b450100 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x7ff02b416a50 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(20)-[UIView:0x7ff02b479a40]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff02b450100 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

That's my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipedView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foregroundView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // that was a proposed fix to my problem I found in the internet. Didn't work
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([pinTop, pinLeft, pinRight, pinBottom])

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    
}
```

I'm totally new to setting up constraints via code so I'm not sure how to deal with this. I checked several similar questions I found on stackOverflow but nothing helped me here, unfortunately.

Comment: Tried that. Though I didn't find such a function, only a boolean value to set to false

Comment: You tried the thing about `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint` that the accepted answer links to?

Comment: I tried that as well, yes. And now it works (I had to change something, see ZGski's answer). I don't know why. I'm gonna post an answer

Answer (score 2):

Set *`swipedView`*'s `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, not `view`'s.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipedView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foregroundView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // that was a proposed fix to my problem I found in the internet. Didn't work
        swipedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: swipedView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([pinTop, pinLeft, pinRight, pinBottom])

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

---

The reason this solution ends up working can be found in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco).

> Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional constraints to modify this size or position without introducing conflicts.

When setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to *`true`*, we're saying that we want the related view's size and position to be turned into actual constraints.

By setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to *`false`*, we are saying that the related view's size and position should not be turned into constraints for whatever reason (in this case, we're creating our own).

Since we're **not** looking to apply constraints that modify both the size and position of `view`, but actually `swipedView`, we need to set `swipedView`'s `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` equal to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when using interface builder and the solution was to identify the constraint that is causing the warnings (possibly by commenting them out one at a time in this case) and then setting the priority of that constraint to 999 rather than 1000 (which I think is the default). Programmatically, you do this with:

```
constraint.priority = 999
```

(Replacing 'constraint' with whatever the affected constraint is.)
This has worked for me a few times and doesn't affect the layout, but clears the warnings. I think 999 is the equivalent of saying "get as close as you can, but don't worry about it" so you don't get the warnings if the constraint fails to be satisfied by a tiny amount. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that every single constraint was causing this error (I tried commenting them out one by one).

Answer (score 0):

Use the technique mentioned in this article:
http://travisjeffery.com/b/2013/11/preventing-ib-auto-generated-at-build-time-for-view-with-fixed-frame-when-using-auto-layout/

The reason why it didn't work for me was the mistake I made with

`view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

It has to be

`swipedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Now it works. I don't know why (maybe some can explain?)

Thanks @ZGski and @dan

Comment: If the answer I provided ended up doing the trick, would you mind marking it as accepted please

Comment: I'm not sure because without adding those constraints in the storyboard (and deleting them at runtime) your answer won't work. It's the combination of both. The rules considering such things are quite strict on stackoverflow so I'm unsure.

EDIT: If you could add this to your answer, I'd be glad to mark it as the correct answer :)